# Customizing Wix UI to ask user to enter their IP Address

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to read an system IP address through Wix UI.

When MSI start Installing, before installing the UI should prompt the user to enter the system IP address, DNS name, User Name & Password. I read some of the articles but I didn't understand them.

How can I modify the UI?

Answer (score 0):

First download the [wix sources](http://wixtoolset.org/). Then look files at path: *..\wix\src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib*. There are files with code of standard dialogs, use them like an example. And after that include your dialog and file with dialogs-sequence (for example WixUI_Mondo ) into install project. And then add new link in the dialogs chain according to [this](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/new-link-in-the-chain) link.